# setting session timeout in Grails Spring Security Core Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

Despite searching the plugin docs and general searching, I can't find an answer to this one.  The closest I've gotten is the end of [this](http://www.redtoad.ca/ataylor/2011/01/grails-cross-site-request-forgeries-csrf/) page, which seems to describe setting a Tomcat timeout.  There is an entire section of the plugin docs titled "Configuration Settings Now in Config.groovy", is there no way to configure timeout for the plugin without involving the container's settings?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The plugin doesn't have settings for session duration - it just uses whatever is configured for the whole app. You can do this by editing web.xml (run `grails install-templates` if you haven't yet) and edit `src/templates/war/web.xml`. Add

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

before the `welcome-file-list` element and set the `session-timeout` value to whatever number of minutes you want it to be.

Comment: Does this approach work for non-Tomcat containers? I know very little about what happens with Grails apps once they get war'ed up.

Comment: Yes, the web.xml file is read by all containers since it's part of the servlet spec. Containers often also have container-specific descriptors, e.g. jboss-web.xml, but those are in addition to web.xml

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I thought Grails includes web.xml? It `install-templates` required?

Comment: If you don't run `install-templates` Grails uses the default template that's part of the installed Grails distro. When you run `install-templates` they get copied to your app, and those are used instead.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith After doing  `install-templates`, is it ok to remove everything in `web.xml` and leave only the timeout setting, then move the file to `web-app/WEB-INF`, right?

Comment: No, don't delete anything unless you have a good reason and know what you're doing. Everything there is included in the final file, plus extra elements added by Grails and plugins

Comment: Hi Burt, I am using grails 2.3.7. I have installed the templates and made the changes as you mentioned. After generating the war file, I checked up the contents of the war. The changes do reflect in the war file. However session timeout does not occur.

Comment: See this link for how to set session timeout for grails 3 applications http://nimavat.me/code-snippets/grails3-session-timeout