# Accesing LoggedIn User Info outside Grails Application Using Spring Security Core PlugIn

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using Spring Security Core Plug In in my grails application. I want to ask One Thing:

How can we access the logged In user Info (Username, id etc.) outside grails application. I want to access it in src/groovy directory. Is there any way for this?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004897/springsecurityservice-log-other-user-out/26009441#26009441) for an example on getting ```SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT``` using an ```HttpSessionListener```. It might help get you started. I don't quite understand your second question. Can you use some type of root path such as ```http://www.example.com/downloads/```?

Comment: Thanks for your first answer. I look into that. Secondly paths are simple for example user may set E:/downloads etc. So files will be downloaded in this directory. And later on when I try to access files from this path I got forbidden. Actuallt, I want to set this path for option [permitAll] so that I may access files in this directory.
P.S. I cannot specify this URL in Config static mapping as It may change at rum time

Comment: And regarding your first answer. You are getting springSecurityContext using HTTPSession while in my case I don't have this. I have simple methos let's say abc() { //Here I want to get the name of the Logged IN User } and in that method I want to access that

Comment: If your ```abc()``` method is called from a controller or service, you can pass ```springSecurityContext``` as an argument. Otherwise, I think you'll need access to ```HttpSession``` in your ```src/groovy``` class. I'm still confused about your second question. Do you mean an E:\downloads directory on a user's computer or on your server? Spring Security protects URLs and not file system paths.

Comment: Yes E:\downloads directory is on a user's computer. User actually is mentioning the path where he wants the downloads to take place. Now, the files are stored in user's specified path but issue comes when application tries to access files from this directory. Spring Security is restricting access to this path which I don't want to

Comment: you have to split your question, otherwise it WILL get closed for being to broad

Comment: if you want to access the user out of some classes under `/src` it doesn't mean "access from outside of the grails app" at all. It simply means that additional effort is required to do that. See my answer for details

Answer (score 2):

if you want to access the `UserDetails` instance not from Grails artifact, you have 3 options:

1) you can pass `springSecurityService` as a method argument or get it from `grailsApplication` or `applicationContext` as a spring-bean. As soon as you have the service at hand, you can call `springSecurityService.currentUser` to get the user details

2) you can grab it out of `httpSession` by `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` as a session attribute.

3) you can grab it from `ThreadLocal` variable via `SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication`

Comment: 1. For your first option: I am calling this method from 'resource' directory of grails application so not sure that either we can inject 'springSecurityService' object or not in resource directory.

Comment: 2. For your second answer: Can you please tell em that how may I get HTTPSession ? I know once I get this I xan gett the SpringSecurityContext(HTTPSession)

3. I have tried your 3rd option too and by this way I get 'Anonymous User'

Comment: you can get the `session` (instance of HttpSession) only in controllers or taglibs, which is natural

Comment: 3. should work as soon you call in within the same application process

Comment: Hmm... So then  your first option is not applicable at all. Only Second Option seems possible If get succeed getting HTTPSession Object

Comment: when you call 3. are you logged in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62319/discussion-between-bilal-ahmed-yaseen-and-injecteer).

Comment: yes I am logged In that time and I get username as "_ANONYMOUS_USER_"